# Getting values from text-boxes, on form submit

Tags: .net, asp.net, listview, textbox

Say I have a ListView control with a TextBox control in the ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:ListView ID="aspectsAndRatings" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:TextBox ID="rating" runat="server" />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

When this form gets posted (by clicking the Submit button) I want to extract the values that have been entered into the text-boxes.

I could, of course, just do the following:

```
Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$aspectsAndRatings$ctrl0$rating"]
```

But I'm sure ASP.NET provides a cleaner way to get the values entered, for each row of the ListView. I just can't remember what it is.

(I did try listView.Items[n].FindControl("rating"), but it returns the textbox with an empty value, rather than the value the user entered.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get values using the code below in a postback handler. Just rememeber not to re-bind your repeater at the page load event.

```
foreach (var item in aspectsAndRatings.Items)
{
    TextBox textBox = item.FindControl("rating") as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        string textValue = textBox.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I would do, however, it may be worth using the `as` keyword and checking the item for `null` first. `TextBox textBox = item.FindControl("rating") as TextBox;` and then `if(textBox != null){ string textValue = textBox.Text; }` as I believe this solution is quicker and safer.

Comment: @csharpsi Well said. Editing the answer as you suggest. Thanks.